# Validator enable using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a custom validator in each sections (rendered as tabs). when you are in one tab the other tab is hidden. so when i continue further to submit i have to disable client validation for the hidden section.
So i call ValidatorEnable(, false);

but it errors out as val.Style is undefined. How to fix this..

I have gone through the following question already
[Enable/disable RequiredValidator on client-side / CustomValidator not firing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699445/enable-disable-requiredvalidator-on-client-side-customvalidator-not-firing)
it didnot help me.

Immediate help plssss

Comment: You should take a look at jQuery BabySteps plugin http://static.coryodaniel.com/stuff/examples/babysteps/index.html

Comment: any code to check this behavior?

Answer (score 6):

Is it possible that you are passing just the ID of the validator to the ValidatorEnable() method?
You need to pass the element itself, then it works ok:

```
ValidatorEnable(document.getElementById('requiredfieldvalidatorID'), false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if the element "val" exists .