# Using RequiredFieldValidator to check if at least one of the two textboxes has some text inside?

Tags: asp.net, validation, requiredfieldvalidator

I have two textboxes on my asp.net page and a submit button. How can I use a single or more RequiredFieldValidators to check if at least one of the two textboxes has some text inside on submit button click?

Comment: possible duplicate of [asp.net validate textbox - at least one text box must have data in](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1443545/asp-net-validate-textbox-at-least-one-text-box-must-have-data-in)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Along with two text boxes add a CustomValidator and call server side validation.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<br />
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<br />
<asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="CustomValidator" OnServerValidate="CustomValidator_ServerValidate"></asp:CustomValidator>
<br />
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click" Text="Button" />
```

Server side function

```
public void CustomValidator_ServerValidate(object source, System.Web.UI.WebControls.ServerValidateEventArgs args)
    {
        args.IsValid = true;

        if (TextBox1.Text == "" && TextBox2.Text == "")
        {
            CustomValidator1.ErrorMessage = "Enter value in at least one text Box";
            args.IsValid = false;

        }
    }
```

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use ClientValidationFunction attribute with CustomValidator and client side function

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtBoxId1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtBoxId2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:CustomValidator ID="cvId" runat="server" ClientValidationFunction="Validators.DoWork">
error</asp:CustomValidator>

<script language="javascript">
var Validators = {
DoWork: function (source, clientside_arguments) {

    var valid_val = true;

    //get the controls values using jQuery
    var txtBoxId1= $('input:text[id*=txtBoxId1]').val();
    var txtBoxId2= $('input:text[id*=txtBoxId2]').val();

    if (your condition) {
        valid_val = false;
    }

    clientside_arguments.IsValid = valid_val;
}
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if a field is not certainly required you shouldn't use a [RequiredFieldValidator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.requiredfieldvalidator.aspx) instead you can use a [CustomValidator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.customvalidator.aspx).

> RequiredFieldValidator - Checks to make sure the user entered a value.
>
> CustomValidator - Checks the form field's value against custom
>   validation logic that you, the developer, provide.

This quote is from [Using the CustomValidator Control By Scott Mitchell](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020145934/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/073102-1.aspx).

You can also check this [Dynamically enable or disable RequiredFieldValidator based on value of DropDownList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2554840/dynamically-enable-or-disable-requiredfieldvalidator-based-on-value-of-dropdownl) because if you are supposed to use a RequiredFieldValidator you will need to disable one of the two dynamically if one of the TextBox is valid.