# Validate a control only if a separate user-control is used

Tags: asp.net, validation, user-controls

In our `asp.net` app we have a user-control that allows users to upload files, on the page I am working on now I need to check if a `textbox` is not empty if, and only if, the user tries to upload a file.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Use a `CustomValidator`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question has already been asking in a slightly different form. If you look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11243662/267903 there is a good answer that you will have to tweak slightly to achieve what you are after.

Comment: Thanks for that! I'll delete this question

Comment: I voted to close so you could get the upvote.