# I'm having trouble understanding page validation

Tags: asp.net

Okay, so I have my asp.net page with all of my comparison and requiredfield validators. This leaves me with two concerns.

1. What additional validation do I need? Do I need anything in the code behind? I want them to be unable to hit the 'save' button until their textbox information is complete, and it seems to be doing this with just the validator controls, but I'm unsure if there are other steps I need to take.
2. If I have a requiredfield validator and I want to turn it off under special circumstances, where in the codebehind would I set it to true? Can I do it on the 'save' button click, before it prevents the button from functioning?

Comment: This may help - [ASP.NET Validation in Depth](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479045.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.

You need as many validations as necessary, you can create many different validators.
You need server-side validation in the code behind. If a postback occurred then the form passed the validation, but there are some validation features which are unusable at client-side. For instance you register to a homepage and you have a form where the username is required and there is a regular expression validator too. These validators will run at client-side. But if the username has to be unique and you can only check that using a database then obviously this can't be checked at the client-side, therefore, the client-side will evaluate the page to be valid, a postback will occur and it's the job of the server-side to check whether the username is unique.

Note that you can create custom validators if you need to do anything exotic.

2.

Depending on your needs you can set the Enabled property of your validators whenever you need to do that. Read more about that [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/126282/Dynamically-Enable-or-Disable-Required-Field-Valid).

Answer (score 1):

As per my knowledge,

1. We should include a check for "Page.IsValid" on the server side (code behind) whenever we are using the ASP.NET Validators. This would ensure a check at the server side even if the javascript is being disabled on the browser.
2. No, you can't do that on the save button click as the button click would not be hit until the validation passes.

Hope this Helps!!

Answer (score 1):

1 if you want add validation server

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {

//Proceed only if the validation is successfull
if (!Page.IsValid) {
 return;}

}
```

2 You can set `CausesValidation="false"` to button

Answer (score 0):

The #1 question with Page.IsValid is ok.

The requiredfieldvalidator is a javascript validator, so you can't disable it from codebehind once it was enabled (unless it satisfies the condition and you can go through). But it's possible to disable it via javascript, check this code:

```
ValidatorEnable(workPhoneValidator, false);
```

Link: [Dynamically enable or disable RequiredFieldValidator based on value of DropDownList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2554840/dynamically-enable-or-disable-requiredfieldvalidator-based-on-value-of-dropdownl)